# Declare python class, and create class instances. (Core Python Programming)

Tags: python

I'm learning python out of "core python programming 2nd edition"

Im stuck at the part "How to Create Class instances". Page 84.

The example is as follows:

classes.py:

```
class FooClass(object):

    """my very first class: FooClass"""

    version = 0.1 # class (data) attribute



def __init__(self, nm='John Doe'):

    """constructor"""

    self.name = nm # class instance (data) attribute

    print'Created a class instance for', nm



def showname(self):

    """display instance attribute and class name"""

    print 'Your name is', self.name

    print 'My name is', self.__class__.__name__



def showver(self):

    """display class(static) attribute"""

    print self.version # references FooClass.version



def addMe2Me(self, x): # does not use 'self'

    """apply + operation to argument"""

    return x + x
```

Then i have to create Class Instances:

in my interpreter i do the follow:

```
Import classes *
fool = FooClass()
```

But nothing happends. It should print the **init**.

also when i use

`fool.showname()` and `fool.showver` it doesn't print any. It says

> FooClass' object has no attribute 'showver

i really want to know what going on here, before i proceed.
Hopefully someone can help me out!

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Are you entering `import` with capital I or lower case i?

Comment: Is that how your code is indented in the file?  I.e. the `def` lines are at the same level as the `class`?  If so, they don't belong to the class and are functions, not methods.

Comment: Are the functions actually in the class definition or are they separate?

Comment: @limelights im entering import with lowercase i.

DSM: Yes, that's how it indented in the book aswell. Changed it right now, that the methods are tabbed under class

Volatility: not 100% sure what you mean. I'm fairly new to all this :P

Comment: I haven't seen this syntax `import classes *`  If you have a module named classes it is usually `from classes import *` or just `import classes`

Comment: +1 on the question. A good example, how SO if for all programmers that have shown effort and ask questions in a proper way.

Comment: @EricRoper i tried `import classes` but that also failed.

Comment: @KevinvanHengst fix your class indentation following one of the answers below and do either >>> `from classes import *` >>> `fool = FooClass()`  or >>> `import classes` >>> `fool = classes.FooClass()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you haven't indented the methods of your class.  With the following code:

```
class FooClass(object):
    ...

def __init__(self, nm='John Doe'):
    ...
```

You are declaring a class called `FooClass` and a function called `__init__`.  The class will have a default empty constructor. If you instead indent it as:

```
class FooClass(object):
    ...
    def __init__(self, nm='John Doe'):
        ...
```

You have a class `FooClass` with the `__init__` method as a constructor.

Comment: Thx! it's working now! Not only the indents were wrong. I also left space between all Methods. Thx for the help! :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, i am also learning python and i am also referring this book but my book is 1st edition. But, what i analyzed from your code is that it is not indented properly.Please check properly and hope so it will work fine.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have indentation problems. Much like the code in functions, conditionals and loops has to be indented for Python to treat it as "inside" them, your various class methods need to be indented past the `class ...:` line to be *part of* the class rather than merely (separate) functions that happen to be defined *after* it. So,

```
class FooClass(object):

    """my very first class: FooClass"""

    version = 0.1 # class (data) attribute



    def __init__(self, nm='John Doe'):

        """constructor"""

        self.name = nm # class instance (data) attribute

        print'Created a class instance for', nm
```

and so on for the rest of your methods.